# How to see if RichTextBox value appeared on the UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a `LongListSelector` and use inside it a `RichTextBox`

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

because of a long list of data, there is a delay in appearing `RichTextBox`'s data. everything is loaded but texts appear later.

No problem with a delay, but It gets annoying when I try to scroll to a particular item in `LongListSelector` by its `.ScrollTo` method. In the `Loaded` event handler of the form or the LLS (no difference) I call `ScrollTo` but its execution finishes and scrolls to the item before appearing the text of `RichTextBox` on the screen, So after appearing the text, it gets longer, and it is not on the right item any more.

I thought of a delay in executing the `ScrollTo` method, to let everything appear in the screen, but since my app is not multithread, I couldn't end up with a successful sleep or timer.

How can I solve this? How can I wait until `RichTextBox`'s loading finished?
(It's a WP8 app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using LayoutUpdated(), the last time it fires the content is loaded.

Comment: Thank you, that's good. But how can I know it is the last time?

Comment: If i'm correct it triggers:
1) When you enter page
2) 3 times when you change content.

So make something like i++
if (i==4)
MessageBox show.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. but I see `LongListSelector` retrieves new items as you scroll so it got fired. But I know how to deal with it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement [Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

```
public class YourClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private string description;
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public string Description
      {
          get { return description; }
          set
          {
              description= value;
              OnPropertyChanged("Description");
          }
      }

      // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
      protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
      {
          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
          {
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
          }
      }
  }
```

And when you set `Description = "blablabla"` it will notify your `RichTextBox`.

Hope it's help

Comment: Thanks @jimpanzer I already have implemented this. RichTextBox gets updated as value changes, but late. I scroll to item 40 and it goes to item 40, but because RichTextBox has delay, It's height grows after I scroll. so at the end I'm on item 30 because of height growth.

Comment: post value witch you put in RichTextBox.

Comment: I use binding. I have a richtextbox for each Item.